# Unexpected Identifier with api url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api

My code takes input from the users, and saves them by functions in local storage to global variables first_name, last_name and domain. I try to pass these variables to the hunterIO api in my code through the function ajaxing using jquery. For some reason the code throws up an unexpected identifier in the url part of the code.

```js
document.querySelector('#url_But').addEventListener("click", ajaxing, false);

function ajaxing() {
  $.ajax({
    f_url = "https://api.hunter.io/v2/email-finder? 
      domain="+domain+"first_name="+first_name+"&last_name="+last_name+
      "&api_key=[REDACTED]"
    //  Error gets thrown here ^^ 'Unexpected identifier'
    url: f_url,
    type: 'GET',
  }).done(function(dataObj) {
    console.log(dataObj.data.first_name);
  }).fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("Error: " + xhr.status + " " + textStatus);
  })
};
```

I am also worried that after fixing this issue another will be thrown up. Because learning api querying through jquery has been a journey from hell.

Comment: Don't put make your API keys available to the public. I've edited it out for you

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues. Firstly, you cannot define a variable inside an object. Move the `f_url` declaration outside of `$.ajax()`. Secondly, you cannot have line breaks in a string. You can either place it all on one line, concatenate the separate lines, or use a template literal. Try this:

```js
document.querySelector('#url_But').addEventListener("click", ajaxing, false);

function ajaxing() {
  let f_url = "https://api.hunter.io/v2/email-finder?domain=" + domain + "&first_name=" + first_name + "&last_name=" + last_name + "&api_key=[REDACTED]"

  $.ajax({
    url: f_url,
    type: 'GET'
  }).done(function(dataObj) {
    console.log(dataObj.data.first_name);
  }).fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("Error: " + xhr.status + " " + textStatus);
  })
};
```

Finally note the missing `&` before the `first_name` property in the URL.

Comment: Still throws up some lovely errors, this time in my jquery.

Comment: see https://gyazo.com/46774df8179c38ea680e37834be366a3. And my whole code if you would be kind enough to have a gander through it. Pretty simple html and im fairly new. Code: https://codeshare.io/arVXrv Seems to be an error with my jquery itself but I doubt that.

Comment: That's not an error in your code. That's a 400 response from the API you're calling. This means your request is being sent, but the data it contains is not what the API expects. I'd suggest checking their documentation to ensure the format of the data meets their requirements

Comment: Confused as to why it isn't accepting my data though. The link https://api.hunter.io/v2/email-finder?domain=asana.com&first_name=Dustin&last_name=Moskovitz&api_key=0409bb7315acf3ed037b22818e10fd51ff7be5e4 works completely fine, even when used in the code, so why should it changed when its working with variables? I hate html aha https://gyazo.com/7be81e8148ae01d2e7a6a3596de20d31 bottom ajax works fine

Comment: Then the content of `domain`, `firstname` or `lastname` is causing the problem. Check their values before you send the request to make sure they are what you expect them to be

Comment: Im such a fucking idiot I forgot an & sign. I've learned to check my code properly before chucking it onto stackoverflow, sorry I am under time pressure as this is due tommorow aha. Thank you for your time though all is working kushty!

Comment: Sorry final question. logging the email through console.log(dataObj.data.email) works fine, but saving it to the variable email (defined in global scope let email;) and attempting to log email leads to no output? https://gyazo.com/dd6c382e20f11489d24612cc281234b8 Little confused as surely if it can log (dataobj etc...) then why can't it save it to a variable

Comment: Most likely you are saving it to a variable correctly, but have just discovered one of the 'gotchas' with async logic - ie. you're trying to read a value before it's been set. I'd suggest researching how to work with async methods, such as AJAX.

Answer (score -2):

You must pass the url as first param in `$.ajax()` not declare it inside it as it is a function.

Just declare f_url before the `$.ajax()` and pass it to the url parameter.